# How to read and replace with two arguments file in Cshell?

Tags: csh

I'm trying to make a script what automatically replace a word in the text file.

```
In a.v,
BIRA_0     0
BIRA_1     400
BIRA_2     800
BIRA_3     C00
...

in b.v,
BIRA_0[25:0]
BIRA_0[95:26]
BIRA_0[125:96]
BIRA_0[255:125]
BIRA_1[5:0]
BIRA_1[25:6]
...


Result,

0[25:0]
0[95:26]
0[125:96]
0[255:125]
400[5:0]
400[25:6]
...
```

Of course,  I can use

```
$sed "s/BIRA_0/0/" b.v > result
```

but the problem is that the file `a.v` contains many such replacement cases, so I'd like to make it automatically by Cshell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as `a.v` does not contain any regular expression special characters, then regardless of the shell that you are using you could do something like

```
awk '{printf "s/^%s/%s/\n", $1, $2}' a.v | sed -f - b.v
```

Alternatively, with awk alone:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} {print a[$1] "[" $2}' a.v FS="[" b.v
```